# import vtk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython'

Tags: python, path, conda, vtk

Ok, there are multiple similar errors and no conclusive solution:
System: windows 10, conda 4.10.3, python 3.7.11

In cmd I activated conda virtual environment: `conda activate tensorflow`

I ran

```
import vtk
```

and got back:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\vtkCommonCore.py in <module>
      4     # use relative import for installed modules
----> 5     from .vtkCommonCorePython import *
      6 except ImportError:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3128/2084281522.py in <module>
----> 1 import vtk

D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\vtk.py in <module>
     30     all_spec = importlib.util.find_spec('vtkmodules.all')
     31     all_m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(all_spec)
---> 32     all_spec.loader.exec_module(all_m)
     33 
     34     # import vtkmodules

D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py in <module>
      5 
      6 # --------------------------------------
----> 7 from .vtkCommonCore import *
      8 from .vtkCommonMath import *
      9 from .vtkCommonMisc import *

D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\vtkCommonCore.py in <module>
      7     # during build and testing, the modules will be elsewhere,
      8     # e.g. in lib directory or Release/Debug config directories
----> 9     from vtkCommonCorePython import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython'
```

Previously in conda virtual environment I ran `conda install vtk` and it ran fine.

My path variable contains: D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3

I also searched and found the following folder: D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\pkgs\vtk-8.2.0-py37h1e53df8_200

How else can I troubleshoot?

Comment: I think I had a similar problem with the conda version of vtk, so I used pip to install it.

Comment: @DaveChen, I also tried `pip install vtk`, it did not help.